# Why doesn't CLion highlight Doxygen comments differently?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, doxygen, clion

In CLion (2021.1), it seems all comments are syntax-highlighted the same way, even if they're Doxygen documentation comments. I couldn't find a Doxygen plugin which might help with that. How can I make CLion highlight Doxygen differently?

Answer (score 2):

Since CLion 2021.2 (EAP) the highlighting of Doxygen comments has changed and different from the previous versions. It is consistent with JB Idea now. Please, read [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-25507) about it.
[image: Settings]

Comment: Isn't the same as what I wrote? With the exception of "Doxygen" instead of "Doc Comment" ?

Comment: No. There is C/C++ Language specific color setup, the bug in color layers was fixed. That essentially changes the highlighting in CLion 2021.2 in comparison with previous versions.

Comment: Ah, ok. Could you edit your comment into the answer? And, specifically, say that the Doxygen highlighting color is now different?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, CLion *does* highlight Doxygen differently, but in some of the Themes (e.g. IntelliJ Light), the color chosen for regular and Doxygen comments is the same.

To change that:

1. On the menus, select File | Settings.
2. In the settings dialog, navigate to: Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults.
3. In the settings pane's tree box, navigate to: Comments | Doc Comments | Text.
4. Change the color to something else (I go with 5C8CC0 which reminds me of Doxygen in Eclipse).